# Remove top bar from view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, interface, navigation

I've got one view controller that I want to have a top bar, and another that I don't.

They're both in the **same navigation controller**.

How can I make the **first view controller have no top bar**, and the **second view controller have a top bar**?

---

**Edit:**

If I use `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];` then there will be a black box where the top bar used to be until the next screen completes it's fly in. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this property in your first view controller:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

In the second view controller, in the viewWillAppear, put below line,

```
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

In the second view controller, in the viewWillDisappear, put below line,

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

Comment: This works, but when I want to navigate back and forth between the screens, the top bar is on. I called that code in the viewDidLoad method. Also you've got yes and no the wrong way round :P

Comment: Is it possible to animate this, when the top bar is being removed, there's a big black space...

Comment: There's still a black gap. Could this be due to my running the app in the emulator?

Comment: No.. You set your window color in Appdelegate.m with the color of your background of second viewcontroller.

Comment: What if my background is a texture?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to hide the navigation bar:

```
[self.navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

and in the next view controller set again:

```
[self.navController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

Call methods:

```
[self.navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[self.navController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
```

in your ViewWillAppear method for each view you want to hide/show NavController.

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;` when you want to hide the navigation bar and use `self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;` when you want to unhide it.

Comment: rishi appears to be black when i back segue ? there is any way to remove it?